# Paging Library 3 LoadType.Append is never called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

I'm using paging library 3 , and it is working fine , but when it comes to the remote mediator , the refresh and prepend are called but LoadType.append is never called , it is only saving the first page , any reason why , Thank you

- This is my remote mediator class

```
 package com.yassir.test.mediator

import androidx.paging.ExperimentalPagingApi
import androidx.paging.LoadType
import androidx.paging.PagingState
import androidx.paging.RemoteMediator
import androidx.room.withTransaction
import com.yassir.test.Utils
import com.yassir.test.auth.AuthService
import com.yassir.test.models.Result
import com.yassir.test.models.keys.RemoteKey
import com.yassir.test.room.MovieDatabase
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.InvalidObjectException

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class MovieRemoteMediator(
    var authService: AuthService,
    var database: MovieDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int,Result>() {


    override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, Result>): MediatorResult {
        val page = when(loadType){
            LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                Timber.d("Refresh Called")
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state)
                remoteKeys?.nextKey?.minus(1) ?: 1
            }

            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                Timber.d("Append Called")
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state) ?: throw InvalidObjectException("Result is empty")
                remoteKeys.nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(true)
            }

            LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                Timber.d("Prepend  Called")
                return MediatorResult.Success(true)
            }

        }
        val response = authService.getTrendingMovies(Utils.API_KEY,"en-US","popularity.desc",
            include_adult = false, include_video = false,page,"flatrate")

        val endOfPaginationReached = response.results.size < state.config.pageSize

        database.withTransaction {
            // if refreshing, clear table and start over
            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                database.getRemoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
                database.getMoviesDao().clearAll()
            }
            val prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1
            val nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1

            val keys = response.results.map {
                RemoteKey(movieId = it.id.toLong(), prevKey = prevKey, nextKey = nextKey)
            }
            database.getRemoteKeysDao().insertAll(keys)
            database.getMoviesDao().insertAll(response.results)
        }
        return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPaginationReached)
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state: PagingState<Int, Result>): RemoteKey? {
        return state.lastItemOrNull()?.let { movie ->
            database.getRemoteKeysDao().remoteKeysByMoviesId(movie.id.toLong())
        }
    }
    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state: PagingState<Int, Result>): RemoteKey? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { position ->
            state.closestItemToPosition(position)?.id?.let { id ->
                database.getRemoteKeysDao().remoteKeysByMoviesId(id.toLong())
            }
        }
    }

}
```